# Error in converting date and time in r

Tags: r, time, posixct

I am trying to convert "30 Jun 17 5:08 pm -0500" to POSIX time format in R.

```
date <- c("30 Jun 17 5:08 pm -0500")
mydate <- as.POSIXct(date, format="%d %b %y %I:%M %p %z")
```

The returned result is "2017-06-30 18:08:00 EDT".

Obviously, the time is incorrect, it should be 17:08:00.

Answer (score 1):

Your original time is from a `-0500` timezone (5 hours behind UTC), which, assuming it was a standard US time zone, was likely Central Daylight Time, which has that offset. Your current timezone, Eastern Daylight Time, is `-0400` (4 hours behind UTC).

In my case, since my computer is currently in CDT, I get the following result from your code:

```
mydate
## [1] "2017-06-30 17:08:00 CDT"
```

Which is as it should be, since my time zone matches the UTC offset that your time was originally from.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. What a fortunate to have someone from CDT test the code for me. Haha.